# How can I transpose an audio track in Logic Pro X without having the duration changed?

Tags: composition, production, transposition, logic-pro, audio

I'm recording vocal audio tracks, but I don't reach some pitches (like a C2) so i tried singing the parts one octave higher and using the transposition feature in the inspector (Shortcut: "i") setting it to -12. But it seems to be changing the duration of the audio file, but not the region, so when the region ends, the sound is cut abruptly.

Is there a way to fix this? Or any workaround?

If this is useful: I'm using Logic Pro X version 10.4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though Logic has flex pitch and flex time which can both be very useful I prefer actually transposing entire sections of audio files rather than use the transients that the program analyzes for something like what you want to do.

First make a duplicate of the audio file for safety because whatever you do can usually be undone but it is destructive. Select the audio file in the main window and under the main “window” menu select “open audio file editor” (or command-6). Here you can select the segment you want to transpose or the entire file by click dragging. Under the “functions” menu select “time and pitch machine” to open that window. You should be in free mode, not classic, and the destination tempo should be 0% or the same tempo as the original. The transposition is at the bottom in cents so an octave is 1200 cents. Negative values transpose down, positive, up. You can preview the sound (sometimes it previews at a different tempo, don’t know why) or just hit “process and paste”. You can still undo at this point if necessary.

One thing to be aware of, if you transpose any audio file a whole octave you are likely to get a very unnatural sound and also possibly a lot of artifacts. I suggest singing your part in as low a key as you possibly can so your transposition value is not as extreme. For example if the song is in A and you can sing the part in C then you only have to go down -300. Good luck, hope this works for you.

Comment: I'm with John on the 'don't try to shift it too far' aspect. An alternative approach might be to sing the rest as written but when it comes to the low C (assuming we're in CMaj) then sing the lowest harmony above that you can properly reach, eg E. A shorter shift & you can sing it against the track without it feeling out of key at the performance stage.

Comment: @Tetsujin that’s a good idea in order to minimalise editing. I’ve never tried pitch shifting a single note of a phrase more than a half step, do you think the timbre of the edited note would stand out?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not sure how good Logic's shifting is. I doubt it's poor, if you find the right algorithm. They all tend to have a few ways to do this type of thing these days. tbh. It's the kind of task I'd try in the DAW & also in Melodyne, see which worked best.

Comment: @Tetsujin Logic has two ways to do it, the way I described and also Flex Pitch, which is Melodyne-ish. It analyzes the waveform and creates a piano roll style window for editing the individual notes. I’ve used them both and  each has its advantages and disadvantages. Looks like a pitch shift experiment is in my future.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I do have Logic (I've always been proud of the fact I was handed my first ever version 1.0 by Dr Lengeling himself, when I visited there in the early 90s); I used to have to use it for work, but it's been so long since I last even launched it I can't remember where anything is any more ;) I've been Cubase since it was Pro 24 on Atari ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Flex Pitch, if you are determined to transpose regions then I'd make sure you turn on flex and follow, it will keep everything the same except for pitch.